# hql: cast string to long

Tags: java, hql, hibernate-mapping

when I try to cast a string in my repository I got invalid request
how can I cast  entity2_ID to long without change it to an object inside Entity1?

```
public class Entity1{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Entity2_ID")
    private String entity2_ID;
}

public class Entity2{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
}

public interface Entity1Repository extend JpaRepository<Entity1, Long>{

    @Query("select e1 from Entity1 e1 where cast(e1.entity2_ID as long) in (:entities)")
    List<Entity1> findAllById(@Param("entities") List<Entity2> entities);

}
```

Comment: Why have a `String` id stored when in fact it's a `Long`?? Just change the `Entity1` really, makes your life greatly easier

Comment: No I can't change it because is already existing project and the changes can damage other part in the project.

Comment: Hm, another way I can think of is passing a `List<Long> entityIds` instead of a `List<Entity2> entities` into your method

Comment: Why not just semi join the two entities? I mean, your `List<Entity2>` is probably produced by a query, so why run another query when you could have semi joined the original one? E.g. `where e1.entity2_id in (select e2.id from ...)`